# Should a structure be refactored into smaller structures?

Tags: refactoring, parsing

In one of the projects (in C), I have the code that looks like this (***the names are obfuscated specially for question to not give out details of the probject***):

```
typedef struct Module_s {
    /* These fields are parsed by f1() */
    S1 *s11;
    S2 *s12;
    size_t n11;
    size_t n12;
    int i11;

    /* These fields are parsed by f2() */
    S2 *s21;
    S3 *s22;
    S4 *s23;
    char *c24;

    /* These fields are set by f3() and later */
    void *v31;
    bool b32;
    S5 s33[N];
    bool b34;
} Module_t;

{
    /* Read only header of file and
     * parse first 5 fields to determine how to load the rest. */
    Module_t *module = f1(input_file);

    /* Read the rest of file using information set by f1()
     * and determine how f3() should preprocess it. */
    f2(input_file, module);

    /* Preprocess the file using information provided by f1() and f2(). */
    f3(module);

    /* Process the file using the information provided by f2() and f3(). */
    f4(module);
}
```

Then, the question is, is it a good move to separate the `Module_t` into 3 smaller chunks, which will contain corresponding fields, set by each function? Then each function will only accept and return a smaller part of `Module_t`, which is probably good, but may complicate further development as interconnections become more complex — and keeping all the dependent fields in one place looks simpler.

What I have in mind is this:

```
typedef struct SS1_s {
    /* These fields are parsed by f1() */
    S1 *s11;
    S2 *s12;
    size_t n11;
    size_t n12;
    int i11;
} SS1_t;


typedef struct SS2_s {
    /* These fields are parsed by f2() */
    S2 *s21;
    S3 *s22;
    S4 *s23;
    char *c24;
} SS2_t;


typedef struct SS3_s {
    /* These fields are set by f3() and later */
    void *v31;
    bool b32;
    S5 s33[N];
    bool b34;
} SS3_t;


typedef struct Module_s {
    SS1_t ss1;
    SS2_t ss2;
    SS3_t ss3;
} Module_t;


{
    /* Read only header of file and
     * parse first 5 fields to determine how to load the rest. */
    SS1_t *ss1 = f1(input_file);

    /* Read the rest of file using information set by f1()
     * and determine how f3() should preprocess it. */
    SS2_t *ss2 = f2(input_file, ss1);

    /* Preprocess the file using information provided by f1() and f2(). */
    SS3_t *ss3 = f3(ss1, ss2);

    /* Compose module and
     * process the file using the information provided by f2() and f3().
     * Store ss1 as well for future use. */
    Module_t module = f4(ss1, ss2, ss3);
}
```

So, should I refactor the structure into smaller substructures?

Comment: Are these your real variable- and function names? If the answer is "yes", then you have an obvious starting point for refactoring.

Comment: @mri No these aren't

Comment: "accept and return"... You don't return anything since it's a pointer. You edit the memory in place. I wouldn't have splitted it unless I needed to because of caching issues.

Comment: @iveqy question edited to include what I type of code I have in mind

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at this from a purely technical point of view, and that's the problem.

You're asking for a design decision for something that appears to be a domain model, and the design of the domain model should be based almost completely on domain knowledge (i.e. what you have obfuscated) rather than technical details of which part is parsed by which function.

If your "three smaller chunks" represent parts of the model that are *conceptually coherent* (for which a good criterium is whether you can give them a meaningful name), then yes, you should split it up that way. If not, then don't. The point of design is to make the code easier to understand, and a model is most easily understood when its structures closely reflect domain concepts.

Of course, there's a good chance that this is what you're already doing anyway and those chunks are processed by different functions exactly *because* they are conceptually separate. But your obfuscation makes it impossible to tell and thus impossible to answer the question.

Comment: +1, if I could, I would upvote this 10 times. I have seen this attitude of trying to make design decisions without understanding the domain far too often in my programmers life.